# Launch Citrix session from command line

Tags: mac-osx, shell, citrix, osx-snow-leopard

Work has a Citrix server.

My workstation is OS X 10.6.8.

I noticed yesterday that if I have  download an .ica file to disk I can launch it from the command line ...

```
open agljava.ica
```

This is nifty, if one wants to launch a session to a published Citrix app from shell, which I do.

But it deletes the .ica file when the session terminates.

How do I keep it from doing that?

Answer (score 2):

In the .ica file edit so this is valid

RemoveICAFile=no